# I want to play dailymotion video from URL in iOS 7 its not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I want to play daily-motion Video from URL in `iOS 7` its not working

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xwxfk5";
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
DMPlayerViewController *mpWatchController = [[DMPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideo:str];
mpWatchController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,39,320,186); 
[mpWatchController play];
```

Comment: The link needs to be to an actual video file, not to a webpage hosting a video through a player. You probably can't play the dailymotion video with your mpWatchController unless there's a way to get the address of the video file itself.

Comment: @Navnath -- good (and much-needed) edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't play the video because you need to supply your player with a direct link to a video file (ending in .mov or .mp4 for example), not to a webpage, like Dailymotion, which hosts a video through a player.

Comment: But how can we get direct link for that video from UIWEBVIEW?

Comment: @Jenifer you can't get a direct link to a video file through dailymotion. By "direct link" I mean an url that ends in .mp4 or .mov or .avi or some other video extension.

Comment: Any way to do it? Actually I wants to do same for Multiple Video hosting websites.

Comment: @Jenifer No, not for sites link Dailymotion or YouTube or Vimeo where they don't supply the file URL.

Comment: There is app named as "Download" on app store which do same stuff. By open video in UIWebView they provide option for download it.

Comment: @Jenifer I suspect we're talking about 2 different things here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79007/discussion-between-jenifer-and-lyndsey-scott).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you use `DMPlayerViewController` - official Dailymotion iOS player. In this case you should pass not `@"http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xwxfk5"`, but `@"xwxfk5"`. Change your code:

```
NSString *URLString = @"http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xwxfk5";
DMPlayerViewController *mpWatchController = [[DMPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideo:URLString.lastPathComponent];
mpWatchController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,39,320,186); 
[mpWatchController play];
```